# WatchOS2 Heart Rate

Tags: ios, healthkit, watchos-2

Hi fellow developers,

We had to wait for it but it's finally here.. or isn't it?

Just a regular question about the new heart rate option in Watch OS 2 beta. Can my running app benefit from heart rate monitoring every second or do we have to use the healthkit version which only refreshes every 10 minutes (or so?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer: You should use HealthKit as it refreshes every 5 seconds during a workout.

Ok, I did my research watching the WWDC 2015 - What's New in Healthkit video (https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=203). If you skip to ~32:00 minutes, the keynote speaker called Mark is implementing Healthkit in it's Watch App. The BMP is monitored after authorizing on your iPhone the app may use HealthKit and will refresh the heartbeat every ~5 seconds. So yes, we can finaly stream the heartrate!

Comment: Have you been able to do this in the background? In my experience, it doesn't exactly stream. It more batches the updates until the app becomes active again.